# Download google contacts images using batch API - Node js

Tags: node.js, google-contacts-api

I have gone through the documentation of google contacts API, but didn't get anything fruitfull for Image download.

[Google contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Batch)

When I download the image, using 1 - 1 request, then some of the images are not getting download it is giving use **Batch API** for download

Does the batch API only support XML?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the batch API is XML-only.

Image download requests must be spaced to prevent throttling.

Comment: But, can we use the batch api for downloading images?

Comment: No. The batch API is for downloading XML content only.